# Why when i assign a object stored in a variable to another variable both change when i change one?

Tags: javascript

So i was trying to do this:

```js
    var obj1 = {test:0};
    var obj2 = obj1;
    obj2.test= 2;
    console.log(obj1,obj2);
```

and I expected to return

> {test:0} {test:2}

but returned this

> {test:2} {test:2}

Is this a bug or this is how object behaves?

Comment: This is how objects behave. Unless you explicitly create a new one, both variables contain references to the same object.

Comment: Objects are **mutable** in javascript. So you need to clone it. there are lot of ways, you can achieve: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1))` and `Object.assign`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Object.assign()** method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
var obj1 = {
  test: 0
};
var obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);
obj2.test = 2;
console.log(obj1, obj2);
```

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 0):

Objects are assigned by reference so if you need to make a copy use `Object.assign()`

e.g.

```js
var obj1 = {test:0};
var obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);

obj1.test = 1;
console.log(obj2.test);
// Using ES6
let object1 = { test: 0 };
let object2 = { ...object1 }
object1.test = 2;
console.log(object2.test);
```

Comment: Why are you using spread syntax on an empty object?

Comment: Thanks @Li357. It was a mistake. Fixed

Comment: `Object.assign` is ES6, too.